# Algorithm to find first interval that has at least X length

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, intervals

Given the following ordered intervals:

[0, 2.99], [5 - 7.9], [23 - 24.99], [34 - 48.99]

How can I find the first interval that is at least length of 4 starting at 4.9?
In this case, the correct interval would be [34 - 48.99]

Loop through all intervals is not a solution as the amount of intervals can be quite high

Edit:

@idz Sorry for the poor details. These intervals are datetimes, they start at today midnight and are incremented by 59, for example:

Note the gap between third and fourth intervals

```
23/10/2020 00:00 to 23/10/2020 00:59 is converted to [0, 59]
23/10/2020 01:00 to 23/10/2020 01:59 is converted to [60, 119]
23/10/2020 02:00 to 23/10/2020 02:59 is converted to [120, 179] 
23/10/2020 07:00 to 23/10/2020 07:59 is converted to [420, 479]
```

When everything starts it is a single interval that is [0 - 479]

In the original question I also ommited a detail for simplicity: the length between two intervals is not the difference between right extreme - left extreme
but it is how many individual datetimes between them. ie:
0 - 479 the length is 4
120 - 479 the length is 2

Thank you

Comment: Why is the correct answer [34 - 48.99]? [5 - 9.9] has length at least 3 and occurs before [34 - 48.99]. Have you omitted some aspect or the problem or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Sorry, you are totally right. I edited the intervals

Comment: I don't see how you would do this without looping through the intervals. Depending on what you mean by `starting at`, you could exclude some of them, but to see where to start, you'd have to (again) loop over the intervals until you get at your starting position. In general, `O(n)` behaviour is almost never considered bad, so how come you feel it is?

Comment: Starting at could be found with bisection O(logn) and if every interval has a pointer to the next interval which is bigger than itself you might get quite good performance unless the interval lengths have a tendency to get bigger. Still O(n) though.

Comment: You may need to give more information. How do the intervals become known to the algorithm? Are many queries carried out on a constant set of intervals? Are intervals added and deleted?

Comment: @maraca Given that the OP has not come back with more info, I accept your criticism that my answer more of a comment that an answer and I have deleted it. I still think with sufficient information about the data you can come up with an O(log n) solution.

Comment: Maybe describe the high-level problem you are trying to solve. For example, "trying to find time slots for appointments/jobs". It seems you have a partial solution to a problem and are describing implementation details of that solution, so it's hard for an outsider to figure out what's going on. For example, if we start with a single interval [0, 479] then what is the length? You say it's the number of datetimes in between, but at the start are there any? I'm just really trying to see the bigger picture.

Comment: Given the current description, you might want to look (for inspiration) at how memory allocators work. They start with a block of memory (a range of addresses) and try to divvy it up to meet requests. As requests are met the free memory becomes a discontinuous set of intervals. It's not exactly the same, but it is similar.